# I'm stuck and I can't move!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I can't see anything or go anywhere. At first, I thought I was in the void, but I realised I wasn't falling.

I was sitting in a cart and I suddenly realised that the height around me was too small, so I started to lose health from suffocation. Suddenly my PC turned off; when I turned it on again, I was stuck and couldn't do anything. My health bar was full too. How can I kill myself to respawn? Or, better yet, is there a way to get me unstuck?

Comment: u try breaking the blocks?

Comment: I assume this is single-player, but please confirm.  If so, do you have commands (cheats) enabled, or mods installed?

Comment: Welcome to the website and if you have cheats enabled, then you should be able to use the /kill command and automatically die! =)

Comment: I believe your PC didn't turn off just because Steve can't breathe?

Answer (score 4):

(Assuming this is single-player) If you have cheats enabled, you can use /kill to kill yourself. You can also try facing down and attempting to disembark from the Minecart. You can also use third-party programs such as [MCEdit](http://www.mcedit.net/) to move the player entity out of the structure. Hope this helps!

Comment: Cheats can also be enabled by opening the world to LAN and choosing the Cheats option.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're probally stuck in there, you can try to break the blocks you're stuck in. otherwise you can use the /kill command.